# in tomcat directory what files are version-specific

Tags: tomcat

In tomcat directory what files are version-specific? Means when tomcat is updated, which files from the previous tomcat directory could override in new tomcat directory and the working of updated tomcat would not get affected as I am currently trying to update tomcat of a running website. Kindly help to decipher which files in the current directory that are essential for the website or which will be changed because of version upgrade

Comment: Which version of `Tomcat` runs on your existing setup?

Comment: Existing is 7.0.54 and I am trying to update to 8.0.51

Comment: Pretty much files (names) remain the same.. only some content is either added or removed from those files depending on the new features and its implementations. However there are new files added to the server but those are few. Imp thing to note is that `Tomcat 8`  requires `JDK` 1.7 or newer. Otherwise you'll be fine if there's nothing complex.

Comment: You should assume that *every* file is different. Let's put the question the other way around. The only file that usually contains site-specific configuration information is `server.xml`, and in fact you can tell which files have been modified after installation by their dates. You should copy that out and re-edit the changes into the new server.xml in the new installation.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask this question in a general way (and only add the specific versions in the comments), let me start with the generic answer:

Inherently an upgrade *may* update every single file. It may *introduce* new files, and it may *remove* some files in the newer version. *Nobody* will guarantee which file they'll never touch in future versions, be it because of bugfixes, or because someone found a better way to deal with a given problem.

Thus, the specific problem that you ask for here is none. Just assume that *everything* has changed. Identify *your* custom changes and apply them to the new version. Tomcat configuration - even across versions - doesn't change much. Odds are that you can reuse exactly what you had in 7.0.x in most cases.

My recommendation is to use a diff tool for the OS of your choice and check the differences between a vanilla 7.0.54 and your installed version (to isolate your changes). To answer your question yourself, you might check the diff between 7.0.54 and 8.0.51 as well - I just think that this is not really important.

Speaking about 8.0.51, some hint about the specific version that you're updating to: Tomcat 8.0.x is on a dead end already. Its [end of life will be June 2018](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html), while the 7.0 end of life is not even announced yet. Going to 8.x, you should choose 8.5.x, which will be supported for a lot longer time. Or go to 9.x, just not 8.0.x